# CoffeeScript : Async.js calling functions in parallel

Tags: coffeescript, async.js

I have a set of functions that are independent of each other [each of them returns a value, each of these functions also accept parameters.] and I wish to run them in parallel. 
If i use async.parallel I wont have the liberty to catch the values. 
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The Async library actually does give you access to the results of the async functions. It's right [in the docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel): Second argument to `async.parallel` is `callback(err, results)` - An optional callback to run once all the functions have completed. This function gets a results array (or object) containing all the result arguments passed to the task callbacks.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it worked.But Thanks for writing by.

Comment: But yeah now i have a new problem, I want to pass some value to these functions, now async.parallels doesnt all me to pass function paramters.

Comment: For that you use `async.each`. Read the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how to do this in CoffeeScript:

```
async = require "async"
fns = [
   (cb) -> cb 1
   (cb) -> cb 2
   (cb) -> cb 4
]

async.parallel fns, (results) ->
  console.log results
  # produces [1,2,4]
```

Comment: But what if i want to pass some parameters to the function.?